# Porting from GL10/11 to GL20

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

So I've been working on a project, but for some time, I've been working in libGDX 0.98.

Wanting to do stuff with shaders, I've updated to libGDX 1.41. Now however, textures, fonts, images, that would draw in GL10, don't draw in GL20. Some things draw, some don't. Some fonts render, some don't. My entire project that was working fine before the update now is having major problems.

Additionally, there's some really awful screen tearing that's happening. As things start to happen in the game, the screen will flicker like 1/4 white, torn down some angle towards the middle screen, like a pizza slice being cut out.

I can add elements to a stage, and tell the stage to draw. Some will draw, some will not. They extend the same classes and use the same methods to draw, but some of them simply refuse to draw.

Here's some code from my render thread, in-case someone has any idea what could possibly be going on. I'm really at a loss here as to what to do. There's a lot of comments in the code, as I'm trying to do some debugging.

```
    public void render(float delta)
   {
      super.render(delta);
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      //get debug output info
      float x = getShip().getBody().getPosition().x;
      float y = getShip().getBody().getPosition().y;
      float speed = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getShip().getBody().getLinearVelocity().x, 2) 
                           + Math.pow(getShip().getBody().getLinearVelocity().y, 2));
      //float angle = Math.abs(ship.getAngleInDegrees()) % 360;
      float angle = ship.getAngleInDegrees();

      /*if(!isPaused)
      {


         if(this.game.getSoundController().getPlayingMusic() == null)
         {
            playRandomTrack();
         }
         if(this.ship.playerIsDead() || this.levelCompleted)
         {
            this.time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(this.time > 10)
            {
               this.dispose();
               if(this.ship.playerIsDead())
                  this.game.goToMainMenu();
               else
                  this.game.setScreen(this.game.getNextScreen());
            }
         }
      }*/

      this.world.step(BOX2D_STEP, 6, 2);
      handleInput();
      handleAsteroids();
      handleShip();
      handleShot();
      handleEffects();


      //debugRenderer.render(this.world, this.debugCamera.combined);

      //draws the score text (will draw other UI Text too later)
      this.spriteBatch.begin();
      this.gameStage.act();
      this.gameStage.draw();
      this.game.getWindowStage().act();
      this.game.getWindowStage().draw();
      //handleEffects(this.spriteBatch); //this method must be called between spritebatch begin and end
      this.font.setColor(Color.RED);
      //this.font.draw(spriteBatch, "TESTTESTTEST", 300, 300);
      if(this.debugOutputOn)
      {
         printDebugOutput(x, y, speed, angle, this.spriteBatch);
      }
      this.spriteBatch.end();

   }
```

EDIT: New info, although I'm still having the problem: When I try to force something to draw but creating it and adding it to the stage manually, a large white rectangle appears in the upper right corner. These are items that *I know* can draw, because they are being drawn already on the screen, but trying to force them to draw here seems to cause some problems.

Comment: I don't know about `libgdx`, but OpenGL 2 is backwards compatible with OpenGL 1/1.1, so I doubt just changing that is the issue. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Nothing else was changed. LibGDX is a layer on top of LWJGL, so you kinda need to know it to be able to offer help.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo But libgdx uses the ES versions of OpenGL, where OpenGL ES 2.0 is not backwards compatible. Scuba Steve, I don't see any issues in the code above, so maybe it's something to do with your assets or Actor subclasses. What do you mean by "force something to draw"?

Comment: All of those classes extend the libGDX class Image. I'm going to try having them extend Texture, and see if I can get different behavior.

By 'forcing' something to draw, I mean grabbing a texture from the TextureAtlas and giving it coordinates, and adding it directly to the Stage. Which is about the simplest means of drawing something in libGDX. Since it's a game, and I have items, inventory, enemies, etc. that all have physics bodies and other attirbutes attached to them, I was trying to rule out possible issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. There's an object in my stage that invokes the Gl ShapeRenderer. It worked fine in GL10/11, but when I ported, it caused everything in the libGDX Stage that was added *after* this object, not to be drawn. Naturally, it caused most of the problems.

I'm not sure if this is a libGDX bug or if it's an issue with GL20 and calling ShapeRenderer when I was.